# I want to allow a picture (tikzpicture) to exceed bottom margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins

I have a paragraph ending by the middle of the page. Then, I have a tikzpicture, which is just a bit too big to fit in the page. I want to allow it to stay there, even if it exceed the bottom margin.

Here is a (silly) example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In this example, the line jumps to the next page. I want the line to stay in the first page, even if it will exceed the margin.

This is what I get with this example:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: Search for `pgfinterruptboundingbox`/`\pgfresetboundingbox`/`remember picture,overlay`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following, I use the `\raisebox` command to (a) typeset the picture "to the bottom" (raise the content by `-\height`) and (b) specify it to have a height and depth of 0.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-5]

    \raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (0,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{document}
```

[image]

For an environment version, check out the `adjustbox` package, which provides all kinds of box manipulations.

Answer (score 4):

As a last resort:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\enlargethispage{0.009cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]